# How to run an application (.exe) via a button in the main menu created in minecraft

Tags: c#, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am developing a modpack (package with modifications) for minecraft specifically technic. But recently the technic removed modpacks update their system. I made a script in C # to help me with this. It ran everything perfectly, but when using the mod called "Custom Main Menu" there would be the possibility of making when I clicked the button that I created it launched the program?

*Link to mod:* [*CustomMainMenu - CurseForge*](http://mods.curse.com/mc-mods/minecraft/226406-custom-main-menu)

All assistance is well accepted.

So did the program of the system (in steps):

> 1: Open the program
>
> 2: It connects to the database on my server from my site and checks the versions of that particular modpack. (I used PHP and JSON to perform this step)
>
> 3: Return: Has version? He asks if you want to upgrade, but for this he asks the player to leave the game to the program to make an automatic backup of the worlds he created.
>
> 4: It starts downloading modpack update file. (Usually we use Zip it will depend on who uses this my application on their modpacks. Type the person asked the program, I ask how you want the modpacks be updated and it me of the answer. We compile the application and send the way the person asked).
>
> 5: Finished it, it erases the "mods" folder and the "config" folder to place the new files. And asks the player whether to keep the created worlds.
>
> 6: After having updated it asks for the player to run the technic again and have fun with modpack. :)

.

> See too: *[CustomMainMenu on Youtube](https://youtu.be/prJy4znvpuU)*

Comment: According to the CustomMainMenu documentation, all the actions you can do are `openLink, openGui, quit, refresh, connectToServer, loadWorld, openFolder`, none of which seems to run an executable

Comment: Okay. But you how to make some java code to do this?

Comment: I take a doubt. If I make a gui in Pylo MCreator, he put as openGui type and select it, you think it works?

Comment: You can make a GUI to run your own java code, but then you'd be better off by just making a mod instead of writing a C# app. http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Basic_GUI

Comment: In the case how it would work like the openFolder?

Comment: So instead of writing your C# app to update the folder, you make a mod that registers a GUI, and you implement all the features in the GUI. Then from the CustomMainMenu, you can use `openGui` to open your GUI

Comment: But when the game is open you can not modify it at all. So did the application in C #. The GUI would be to if I had to run the program .exe with java code.